# An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, controller

I am working on C# MVC project, and I use a Custom Authorization Method for the actions on the controller, but I need to pass the Controller Name and the Action, this is what I have so far, but is giving me the error on the title, how can I solve this issue?

```
public class ServiceUpdateController : Controller
    {
        [AuthorizeRoles(Accion = "Index", ControllerProgram = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() )]
        // GET: ServiceUpdate
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You cannot pass it as a parameter in the attribute. Attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time. But you can get values within the method.. Show your code for `AuthorizeRoles` and where you need to access it

Comment: @StephenMuecke done, I uploaded as an Image

Comment: Code please, not images of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are metadata and must be known at compile time so you can only use constants (the current controller is not known until run time).

The `httpContext` parameter of your `protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)` method contains the the information about the current request, so you can use

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    string controller = httpContext.Request.RequestContext
        .RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it